# Get Database Context from inside Attached Entity

Tags: entity-framework

In an n-tier app, I've always adopted the approach of returning detached entities from a repository class.  I then manually attach before making changes.  All has been OK until this new scenario ...

I use the following code snippet to access the context from inside an entity:

```
    public abstract class EntityBase
{
    protected TheLeegzDbContext GetDbContext()
    {
        ObjectContext object_context = this.ObjectContext();

        if (object_context == null || object_context.TransactionHandler == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return (TheLeegzDbContext)object_context.TransactionHandler.DbContext;

    }
    private ObjectContext ObjectContext()
    {
        var field = this.GetType().GetField("_entityWrapper");

        if (field == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var wrapper = field.GetValue(this);
        var property = wrapper.GetType().GetProperty("Context");
        var context = (ObjectContext)property.GetValue(wrapper, null);

        return context;
    }
}
```

This appears to work for an object that has not been detached.  However, when I detach it via .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault() and then attach it later, the line:

```
var field = this.GetType().GetField("_entityWrapper");
```

returns null.

To summarise, the above line does retrieve the context if I don't detach the object but fails if I detach and then re-attach the object (note: I attach it to the same context as I used to retrieve it --- not sure if that matters?!).

I'm doing this because when adding a child entity (which was not eagerly loaded) the root aggregate needs to load the child entities to plays with 'ordinals' in case the new child is to be 'inserted'.  So, I want to:

1) Retrieve root object and detach and ... later ...
2) Attach the root object to the context
3) Call "AddChild" to the root object, (child includes a property "Ordinal")
4) Have the root object use GetDbContext().Entry(this).Collection(e => e.Children).Load();  to load the existing child objects.
5) Have the root object manipulate existing child objects to 'shift' the ordinal of the existing children if the new item has an ordinal that requires 'inserting' in the middle of the existing children.

e.g.

```
void AddChild(Child child)

if (this.Children == null)
    GetDbContext().Entry(this).Collection(e => e.Children).Load();

// Update ordinals of some children if new child ordinal requires inserting.
```

Problem is that .Attach of the root does not seem to provide the field "_entityWrapper" as it would just after it is retrieved from the database and still being tracked.

Can I achieve this, or is it necessary that I load the existing children eagerly if I want to insert a new child?

Comment: I see what you're doing, this is an interesting implementation of delayed eager loading, it's like not quite lazy loading... Have you considered simply adding an overload to add that allows you to pass-in the context?

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  Certainly an option but 'ordinal handling' is an invariant behaviour in data-layer itself so kinda wanted the domain layer to not have to know such things.  Sure, the domain layer should know that it needs to attach the entity root to context so changes can be tracked but once that is done the implementation of "Add Child" on that root entity should be encapsulated without Domain knowing to pass in a DBContext.  I thought "attaching" would put the entity back to a state as if it was never detached in the first place.  Clearly not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour that you have identified is by design *IF* you have `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false`.

In that scenario, when you load data with `.AsNoTracking()` the Type of the object returned should be your POCO data class, otherwise EF will return a proxied version of your class that includes the additional field called `_entityWrapper`.

> Your logic conventions depend on `_entityWrapper` being available even when tracking is disabled, **so you should set `ProxyCreationEnabled = true` in your context before you load the data.**
>   As your `EntityBase` class expects this functionality you should either edit the constructor on your context to set the config to force proxies, or use some other factory method to pre-init the context before you use it.
>
> > It would not be suitable to put this inside your `EntityBase.GetDbContext()` because it must be configured in the context before the entity is created.

```
// Force _entityWrapper proxy generation for all queries
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

When you attach your entity back to a context, the type of your object does not actually change magically back to a proxy type, so that explains why if there was no *field* in your object called `_entityWrapper` before attaching, it cannot possibly exist *after* attaching.

To change Type would require a whole new instance of the new type to be created and all property values to be cloned across, you would need an assignment operator to do this. Event trying to access the entity from the Entry that is created will not provide resolve as a proxy type (though i thought it should the first time I tried it), so the following reassignment does not work, the result is still the original item instance:

```
item = dbContext.Entry(item).Entity;
```

> **NOTE:** When Ordinal processing matters and you are trying to manage it in C# *(before updating or inserting child records into the database*) then at the split second before the `Add`, you can never be 100% sure that the items you already have in the collection that you are adding to, you are right to try and load all the items into the list, but `.Load()` will only bring in records that were not already in the list, you should consider refreshing all the *ordinal* fields for the *current* items in the list as well (if there are any), in case any parallel operations may have affected the list since it was last loaded for the current context.

---

Finally, even with Proxies enabled, if your N-Tier structure involves a layer that serializes the objects and subsequently deserializes them the proxy should not normally be attainable at all in the deserialized result, even if the object was being tracked before serialization.